Dirichlet problem for an elliptic operator
consider de Dirichlet problem $Lu=0$ on the unit ball B of $\Bbb C^n$ and $u=f$ on the unit sphere $S^{2n-1}$, we suppose that $L$ is an elliptic operator.
My question is there is a formula of the solution $u$ and the green function of the operator $L$.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Relevant, even if it involves the fundamental solution and not Green's function.
